# How does the Android Market work for developers?

Tags: android, google-play

I have some quetions:

Should I buy any license to distribute my applications?

Which profit from the sale of applications?

(sorry, I dont speak english very well :P )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to publish your application to the Android Market, you have to get a [developer subscription ($25)](http://market.android.com/publish/signup). Once you have a developer subscription, you can publish free apps as much as you like; in order to sell apps, however, you have to be in one of the [countries where you can be a Google Checkout Merchant](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/150324?hl=en). [Google gets 30% of the revenue](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1153481). Also, be aware that the paid apps will be available only in countries that are listed in the [Paid App Availability](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/138294?hl=en&topic=2365624&ctx=topic) list (scroll down).

Comment: @AlexanderGyoshev however as I've found, ads never make any real money

Answer (score 4):

You don't necessarily need the Android market. You can just distribute your *.apk file by yourself (for free or against payment). This is one of the big advantage compared to Apple and the IPhone ;)

The profit you can make with your application depends on the  price of your application and the number of sales.

Comment: Can you give some details as to how you might do this but at the same time limiting piracy of the app? No doubt just allowing direct download of the apk will inevitably see it make its way onto rapidshare. //edit S.O giving really old posts in related, sorry

Comment: I'm not sure about that, but I also never claimed that it will prevent privacy. But you could nevertheless implemented something like an activation or registration by yourself if you spread your app like that. But it really depends on your app. Not all apps are suited for this kind of distribution.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to buy any license to publish in the market.  You should read through the series of documents on publishing apps in the developer guide, starting [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html).

You can either publish your app as a paid app, in which case you could earn money directly from sales, or you could publish as a free app.  With free apps, you can use ads as a source of income.  There are a few providers, i.e. [admob](http://developer.admob.com/wiki/Android).

Comment: Actually, there is a $25 one-time fee in order to publish in the market; Google also takes 30% of your app price.